# Codeigniter: User session keeps expiring

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter, and I'm having a small issue with sessions. I've set 'sess_expiration' in config.php to 0 so that the user session will never expire, yet users -even myself- are still occasionally kicked out and asked to login again! (i'm storing sessions in the DB btw)

The way I validate a user's session is by basically checking if user_id (which I've previously stored in the session is TRUE or FALSE. If it's FALSE then it asks them to login again.

Any idea what could be forcing sessions to expire?

Appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'm curious, which version of CI are you using? I have run into this recently with version 2.0, and had to turn off DB sessions for the quick fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the session expire to some really large number. Try:

```
time()+(3600*24*365*5)
```

or

```
time()+157680000;
```

This session should last you 5 years.

Comment: even thought the codeigniter documentation says to set it at 0 - you should try the alternatives since it doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 3):

If you're making AJAX requests in your app/site I think this may be the issue you are experiencing: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/154

It seems to be a bug in how CI handles AJAX requests updating sessions.