# I want to set the session in codeigniter to never gets expired

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have set `$config['sess_expiration'] = 2592000` and `$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE` in my config file but still it expires the session on browser close. I want the sessions gets stored for atleast 30 days and not even expire on browser close. Please suggest me the way to do it.

I also tried setting the `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0` to never expire the session, but it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500516/codeigniter-user-session-keeps-expiring?rq=1

Comment: Make sure you are NOT: 1. using incognito mode; 2. have `sess_match_ip` set to `true` and you ip changes; 3. clearing out cookies; 4. having a software that handles cookies, like internet security suite